# Can you get the number of times a method has been called in EasyMock or PowerMock?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, powermock, easymock

Or more specifically, can one count the number of calls that a method has been called, and then use that number to set the number of expected times another method will be called?

For example, if I have:

```
expect(userManager.enterSuperUserMode()).andReturn(token).anyTimes();
// count the number of calls...
```

and then

```
expect(userManager.leaveSuperUserMode(token))   // void method
expectLastCall.times(<number of times su mode was entered>);
```

is that possible?

As I'm writing this question out, it actually seems very unlikely since this is all pretty static when the test is `replay()`ed... maybe a different approach would be sufficient? or is this information that has to be known ahead of time?

Comment: Do you really not have handle to know how many times `enterSuperUserMode` was called? Just run the test once and for that set of conditions, you know how many times `enterSuperUserMode` was called. Then use that no. in the both the calls.

Comment: I do, it was more of a curiosity if it could be done. If there were a case where, for instance, you don't know how many times `enterSuperUserMode` will be entered, but you want to ensure that `leave` is being called the exact same number of times

Comment: As you thought, it's not possible - the expectations are set statically. But then, the expectations for a given set of data cannot and should not change (if it did change, the `verify` should take care of it), so your approach isn't the worst.